# Copy column content PostgreSQL 7.4

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the easiest way to copy the all the values from a column in a table to another column in the same table in PostgreSQL 7.4 ?

Comment: Please consider updating. 7.4 is really..... old and without maintenance.

Comment: I am ware of that but cannot do so!

Comment: Hmmm... was afraid about that. Nevermind. Just wanted to mention ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update x set new_column_value = old_column_value
```

Comment: Did not thought it was that simple

Comment: fixed a bug in my answer